# Thymeleaf [# th:each] is not getting parsed

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf (3.0.11.RELEASE) TEXT template with iteration as follows:

```
[# th:each="sei : ${specificInfoElements}"]
[(${sei?.elementLabel})] ： [(${sei?.elementValues})]
[/]
```

The above is not getting evaluated by template engine and its coming as follows in output:

```
[# th:each="sei : ${specificInfoElements}"]
:
[/]
```

Can anybody help me understand what  I am doing wrong?

Note: I am using spring boot.

```
    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine;

    Context thymeleafContext = new Context();
    thymeleafContext.setVariables(templateModel);
    String outputText = thymeleafTemplateEngine.process(emailTemplateString, 
    thymeleafContext);
```

Comment: How are you integrating or calling that from Spring Boot ?

Comment: Yes, I am calling from Spring Boot. Editing question with the required code.

Comment: Have you set `spring.thymeleaf.mode=TEXT` in your `application.properties` ?

Comment: After your comment, I added the property in `application.yml`. Still it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am storing templates in DB, `thymeleaf` is using `StringTemplateResolver` by default. `StringTemplateResolver` is added to the `SpringTemplateEngine` upon calling `process` method for the first time as shown in the code snippet taken from `org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine`:

```
if (this.templateResolvers.isEmpty()) {
   this.templateResolvers.add(new StringTemplateResolver());
}
```

I changed the template mode of `StringTemplateResolver` before calling the `process` method as follows:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(springTemplateEngine.getTemplateResolvers())) {
// calling process method will initialize SpringTemplateEngine with StringTemplateResolver.
   springTemplateEngine.process("template contents", context);
   Set<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers = 
                              springTemplateEngine.getTemplateResolvers();
   StringTemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver = (StringTemplateResolver) templateResolvers.iterator().next();
   stringTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with Spring Boot and it works fine. What I did exactly:

1. Create a new project via start.spring.io using Spring Boot 2.5.1 with Java 11
2. Update `application.properties` with:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=TEXT
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.txt
```

3. Create a file `src/main/resources/templates/test.txt` containing the template:

```
[# th:each="sei : ${specificInfoElements}"]
[(${sei?.elementLabel})] ： [(${sei?.elementValues})]
[/]
```

4. Create a test class that extends from `CommandLineRunner` so I can just start the app and see some output:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("specificInfoElements", List.of(new SpecificInfoElement("first label", "first value"),
                new SpecificInfoElement("second label", "second element")));
        String result = templateEngine.process("test", context);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }

    private static class SpecificInfoElement {
        private String elementLabel;
        private String elementValues;

        public SpecificInfoElement(String elementLabel, String elementValues) {
            this.elementLabel = elementLabel;
            this.elementValues = elementValues;
        }

        public String getElementLabel() {
            return elementLabel;
        }

        public String getElementValues() {
            return elementValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Running this outputs:

```
2021-06-22 08:22:39.229  INFO 13464 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.119 seconds (JVM running for 2.828)
result = 
first label ： first value
second label ： second element
```

I hope this can help you figure out what you are doing differently.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. The difference is I am keeping the templates in DB.

Comment: I found I am using `StringTemplateResolver` which uses HTML as default template mode. Looking how to change to TEXT.